# Graphing and finding sine wave info with $\sin(x/4)$

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I'd doing a chapter on graphing sine waves, and finding the amplitude, period, and so on.

I know something like $y = 2 \sin(3x+ \pi) + 1$ can be turned into $y = 2 \sin[3(x + \pi/3)] + 1$ following the $y = A \sin[B(x-C)] + D$ format, with amplitude 2, period being $(2\pi)/2$, and a phase shift of $\pi/3$. But what do you do with something like $y = 2 - \sin(x/4)$? I don't have any examples with just $x$ divided by something in the book, other then a problem that just gives an unexplained answer.

Comment: ... Ok, nvm I see it now. Needed to think little looser and make different way of putting the equivalent of x/4, as 1/2 * x.

Comment: The period of $$y = 2\sin\left[3\left(x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right] + 1$$ is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: I've always found it instructive taking a one-to-one portion of the sine functions and flipping it around. For example, on $[-\pi, \pi]$ we can flip 
$$y=2\sin\bigg[\color{green}{3}\bigg(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\bigg)\bigg]+1$$
into
$$x=\color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y-1}{2}\bigg)-\frac{\pi}{3}$$
and clearly see the period being stretched by a factor of $1/3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  You can express $$y = 2 - \sin\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)$$ in the form $$y = -1\sin\left[\frac{1}{4}(x - 0)\right] + 2$$